# Can't get the port redirect to work

Tags: networking, webserver, ip, redirect

First of all, I'm very green in ubuntu and now experimenting on my server.

Here's the thing, I want my local ip 192.168.1.140`:6080` to be accesible from the internet via public IP.

Currently I have my router redirecting the port `6080` to my local ip:6080, but when I try to access it I keep getting Page Not found.

What I did:

> 1. Set up the application on port 6080
> 2. Redirect the router port to the same port to local ip.

As I said I'm new here, so please point me in a correct direction.

When I input: `netstat -anltp | grep "6080"`

Here's what is displayed:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:6080          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                313/ssh
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.140:6080      0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN                                -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.140:6080      192.168.1.49:49889      ESTABLISHED                           -
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.140:6080      192.168.1.49:49881      TIME_WAIT                             -
tcp6       0      0 ::1:6080                :::*                    LISTEN                                313/ssh
```

Thank you,

**UPDATE:**

UFW is INACTIVE

**UPDATE 2**

```
/etc/network/interfaces

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
address 192.168.1.140
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.1.0
broadcast 192.168.1.255
gateway 192.168.1.153
dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

**UPDATE 3**

Screenshots - Router config.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/VeqzA.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbQ7o.jpg

Comment: How are you testing, not all NAT's will do hairpin traversal so you may not be able to test from the same network?

Comment: My friend is testing it, also I disconnect from the WIFI on my mobile and try to access it also... Not working on either...

Comment: Does your box 192.168.1.140 have a gateway set?

Comment: Yes, added the interfaces configuration in a question.

Comment: What is `.153` is it a router? I am guessing this `.140` can access the internet just fine?

Comment: On my Windows machine, `ipconfig /all` default gateway is `.153`

Comment: Does `.140` have a working internet connection? eg. can you `ping 8.8.8.8`

Comment: Can your friend establish a connection via `telnet [YOUR IP] 6080` (works on Linux, Mac, and Windows)? Can you post a screenshot of the port forwarding configuration page of your router?

Comment: Yes, without problems.

Comment: Telnet response from mac:
`nodename nor servername provided or not known`

in terminal I wrote: `telnet ip:6080`

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to put images, so atached links

Comment: @Shutupsquare any ideas? Because I'm lost... What is a normal gateway? `.253` ? Maybe I mised something in my ubuntu config? I don't know if this is relative, but I have `apache2` and `postgresql`, the app I'm trying to reach is on Postgre.

Comment: Your gateway is in a regular home network usually the IP address of your router, this is also the place you are probably doing the port forwards. By most defaults a home router will usually have an IP of .1 or .254

Comment: I notice in your image that it says its a NAT rule, is there also a place to open the port in the firewall? This is usually not needed on a home router as they open the firewall when you do the NAT rule, but could be an option.

Answer (score 0):

This could be the firewall blocking try:

```
sudo ufw status verbose
```

If you get something like this

```
Status: active
```

Then you will need to open the port:

```
sudo ufw allow 6080/tcp
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention, I've disabled UFW. Status: inactive

Comment: Also, I had it enabled and had 6080/tcp and 6080/tcp (v6) with action allow. Didn't help either.

Comment: Yeah I see now from your netstat that you had a client connected from another IP so it is unlikely local firewall related.